# Ansible copy module inside a role

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible role that will provision an ubuntu server in Azure. The VM provisioning is working fine for me but I need to copy few files from my localhost to this VM how can I do this?

```html
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
│   ├── cloud-init.yaml
│   └── files.txt
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   ├── copyfile.yaml
│   ├── main.yml
│   ├── apachenic.yaml
│   └── apachevm.yaml
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

Here I have kept the file files.txt (the file I want to copy) in file folder and created a new task file (copyfile.yaml) for copying. Adding content of copy tasks below.

```
     - name: copy certs
   become: true
   become_user: admin
   ansible_sudo_password: pass123
   copy:
     src: files.txt
     dest: /home/admin/
     owner: admin
     group: admin
```

I have tried multiple times re-arranging and creating a new task file getting the below error message.

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: copy, ansible_sudo_password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me looks like your YAML is malformed.
try this: (top level play, lets say, its `copyFilesTXT.yml` )

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: admin
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: copy files.txt file to remote machine
      copy:
        src: files.txt
        dest: /home/admin/
        owner: admin
        group: admin
        mode: 0644
```

this task can be started by  this console invocation

```
/bin/ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass -i hosts.ini copyFilesTXT.yml -vv
```

it will ask for sudo password from STDIN, so you can provide it.

Also, you can omit `--ask-become-pass` and add this variable in `vars/main.yml`

```
ansible_become_pass: pass123
```

so, sudo password will be loaded from `vars/main.yml`

Comment: Thanks, Vodolaz for the quick answer, I am running this role with few other roles, so if I add hosts: all then all the provisioned servers will have the copied file?

Comment: yes, add all hosts to host.ini file, and all data will be copied for them in parallel